# scrapy setting option CONCURRENT_REQUESTS is not working

Tags: python, scrapy

Python 3.6.2, Scrapy 1.4.0, windows 2007

scrapy is working fine, but this option CONCURRENT_REQUESTS is not working.

i set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 64, but the speed didn't change.
cpu rate stays at 20%, this option seems to change nothing.

how can i detect it's actual concurrent_requests and make it run faster

Comment: Did you also tweak [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain) (which is 8 by default)? Is [Autothrottle](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#topics-autothrottle) ON or OFF?

Comment: CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 128
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 64
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
Did i miss anything?

Comment: Try disabling Authothrottle, `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False`